# Best way to optimise an if statement in C#?

Tags: c#, optimization

I was writing an app, and for this piece of code(in the end of a method)

```
if (selectSdfDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Sdf = selectSdfDialog.FileName;
    var regex = new Regex("[VQ]\\d{11}");
    Serial = regex.Match(selectSdfDialog.SafeFileName).ToString();
}
```

Resharper gave me a hint to invert the if statement, bringing it to this

```
if (selectSdfDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
Sdf = selectSdfDialog.FileName;
var regex = new Regex("[VQ]\\d{11}");
Serial = regex.Match(selectSdfDialog.SafeFileName).ToString();
```

My question is, is this working faster or somehow better, and if yes, what is the difference for the compiler?

Comment: it the same and resharper again can give you hint - invert this statement

Comment: It reduces the indentation. Can sometimes make the code more readable IMO.

Comment: @Grundy in that case it's a just a possible command for resharper, but before this it was showing this hint with a yellow(maybe warning) sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a compiler optimization, it's an author optimization. It [flattens arrow code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/).

Comment: I like the last sentence: _"But whatever you do, you have to abandon the ill-conceived idea that there should only be one exit point at the bottom of the function."_